# can't get value inside <a> tag in lxml

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping, lxml, lxml.html

I am using lxml to scrape data from a website. The  html code snippet is

```
<span class="pro-contact-text">
<a class="click-to-call-link text-gray-light trackMe" href="javascript:;" 
   objId="104809" compid="clickToCall_profile_organic" phone="(617) 505-4149"">Click to Call</a>
</span>
```

I can get to the span by using the xpath (Eg. `//*(some tags)/span[@class="pro-contact-text"`] ) and when I print the varible it prints a valid element (Eg. `<Element span at 0x3589510>` )
 When i extend the xpath to { `span[@class="pro-contact-text"]/a/@phone` } it returns an empty list.
Can someone help me to do this.

Comment: Do you mean you use `//*(some tags)/span[@class="pro-contact-text"]/a/@phone` or just `span[@class="pro-contact-text"]/a/@phone`?

Comment: **some tags - basically i just add `/a/@phone` to it

Comment: Can you share exact expression you use? without replacing `**some tags`

Comment: `//*[@id="profileHeader"]/div/div/div/div[5]/div/ul/li[@class="sidebar-item pull-right profile-content-narrow"]/div/span[@class="pro-contact-text"]/a/@phone`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the invalid html.

The attribute `phone` ends with `""` (*two quotes*).

```
phone="(617) 505-4149"">
                      ^
```

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the data ?